# How to sum list elements with the same name?

Tags: r, list, sum, aggregate, lapply

I´m looking for a solution to this problem:
I have a list of lists like this

```
sample = list("element1" = list("term1"=0.5, "term2"=1, "term3"= 4, "term1"= 0.5), "element2" = list("term23"=5, "term1"=2, "term23"=4))
```

For each list of the outer list I would like to sum values with the same name. So the desired output is

```
desired_output = list("element1" = list("term1"=1, "term2"=1, "term3"= 4), "element2" = list("term23"=9, "term1"=2))
```

Actually, I thought of using something like this

```
result = lapply(sample, function(l) aggregate(l, by = list(names(l)), FUN = sum))
```

but that gives me an error. 
Any ideas about this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
lapply(sample, function(y) {lapply(split(y,names(y)), function(x) {Reduce("+", x) })})
```

Output:

```
$element1
$element1$term1
[1] 1

$element1$term2
[1] 1

$element1$term3
[1] 4


$element2
$element2$term1
[1] 2

$element2$term23
[1] 9
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `aggregate`, here is an idea that produces a slightly different output than your expected one

```
lapply(sample, function(i){s1 <- stack(unlist(i)); 
                           aggregate(values ~ ind, s1, sum)})

#or all in one line (compliments of Ronak Shah)
lapply(sample, function(x) aggregate(values~ind, stack(x), sum))

#Or use xtabs to output your expected result (compliments of akrun)
lapply(sample, function(x) as.list(xtabs(values~ind, stack(x))))
```

which gives,

> ```
> $element1
>     ind values
> 1 term1      1
> 2 term2      1
> 3 term3      4
>
> $element2
>      ind values
> 1 term23      9
> 2  term1      2
> ```

Comment: As you are using `stack` another option is `lapply(sample, function(x) as.list(xtabs(values~ind, stack(x))))`

Comment: @akrun great! that also produces the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

We can loop through the `list`, `unlist` and use one of the group by operations

```
lapply(sample, function(x) {
            x1 <- unlist(x)
           as.list(tapply(x1, names(x1), FUN = sum))
      })
#$element1
#$element1$term1
#[1] 1

#$element1$term2
#[1] 1

#$element1$term3
#[1] 4


#$element2
#$element2$term1
#[1] 2

#$element2$term23
#[1] 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Another double loop options with `sapply` where we find the matching names in each list and `sum` their values.

```
sapply(sample, function(x) sapply(unique(names(x)), function(y) 
                           sum(unlist(x[names(x) == y]))))


#$element1
#term1 term2 term3 
#    1     1     4 

#$element2
#term23  term1 
#     9      2
```

If you want to keep them as lists of lists. Use `lapply` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`purrr::map_df` makes it easy to simplify this list to a tidy data frame which is trivial to aggregate:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample = list(element1 = list(term1 = 0.5, term2 = 1, term3 = 4, term1 = 0.5), 
              element2 = list(term23 = 5, term1 = 2, term23 = 4))

sample %>% 
    map_dfr(~data_frame(name = names(.x), 
                        x = simplify(.x)), 
            .id = 'element') %>% 
    group_by(element, name) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups: element [?]
#>   element  name       x
#>   <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 element1 term1   1.00
#> 2 element1 term2   1.00
#> 3 element1 term3   4.00
#> 4 element2 term1   2.00
#> 5 element2 term23  9.00
```